# Does $\epsilon$ in the formula for capacitance correspond to the the permettivity of the body or the surroundings?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

In the formula of the capacitance of spherical shape, $C = 4\pi\epsilon R$. Is $\epsilon$ the permittivity constant of the region around sphere or it is that of the material of the sphere?

Comment: It's the permittivity of the region around the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

It is the permittivity of region around it
In ideal case of vaccum we use it as €○.

Other wise we can put € as €•×€r   where €r is relative permittivity of medium.

Hope it helps.☺